# what was the most significant foundational improvement in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-rc2

Out of the following which one is the most significant improvement in .Net Core?

Reduced framework size?
Being Cross platform?
or Relying on a package management system?

Comment: You probably need to define what "significant" means in this context. Are you looking for the largest change? Something else? Without being more specific, this seems like it could generate a lot of opinion-based answers.

Comment: I believe different people will give you different answers, so this question should be closed, because it's opinion-based.

Comment: It already was reduced and cross-platform.  Linux support is new.  ASP.NET support is new.  Allowing anybody to extend and host the CLR is new.  It is not so core anymore, that's new.  Take your pick.

Answer (score -1):

Its been a while .Net developer were facing issue with windows specific compatibility.With Microsoft core you will be getting [Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com) compiler.Now you can even deploy app from [docker](https://www.docker.com) container which has open a new set of users .Most of the dev prefers to work in Linux, even me. So this upgrade rather a revolution has been a of mutual benefit for microsoft and .net developers.